# Azure: Create user that can log into a web app but not the azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

I've deployed an asp.net web forms application to an app service resource.  I've turned on the app service authentication and set it to Log in With Azure Active Directory.

I've created a guest user account and verified that the user can log in to my application.  That user is also able to log into the azure portal, and although the user doesn't appear to be able to do anything in the portal, they can still get to the portal and see things.   How can I create users that can access my app service but not the azure itself.  And if I have multiple app services, how can I create users that are silo'd to specific app services?

Comment: Onece you invited the user to your directory, the user could also login azure portal. But I also want to make clear that the user can not do anything in your directory and Azure resources if you don't give him/her permissions.

Comment: Ok,  so there's no way to prevent that it sounds like.  Ok, so if I have multiple app services, how do I grant rights to specific ones?

Comment: Well, this can be resolved. Since each Web App liknes to one service principal, you need to set `User assignment required`  to be `Yes` in the Properties for that service principal and only assigned users can access to login access to this app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is  no way to prevent a user which has been your directory to sign in Azure portal. Onece you invited the user to your directory, the user could also login azure portal. But I also want to make clear that the user can not do anything in your directory and Azure resources if you don't give him/her permissions.

> And if I have multiple app services, how can I create users that are
>   silo'd to specific app services?

Well, this can be resolved. Since each Web App liknes to one service principal, you need to set `User assignment required` to be `Yes` in the `Properties` for that service principal and only assigned users (Add users in Users and groups) can access to login access to this app.

[image]